# Don't know how to use ScreenTree create_timer in Godot

Tags: godot

I tried from documentation example

```
func _physics_process(delta):
  yield(get_tree().create_timer(1.0), "timeout")
pass

func timeout():
  print("Working")
pass
```

Answer (score 1):

In the example, the `yield` keyword is used to tell Godot to suspend execution until it receives an specified signal.

So, if you have code that looks like this:

```
print("hello")
yield(object, "signal_name")
print("world")
```

It will print `"hello"`, then after `object` emits the signal `"signal_name"`, it will continue and print `"world"`.

---

Let us put `create_timer` now:

```
print("hello")
yield(get_tree().create_timer(1.0), "timeout")
print("world")
```

Understand that `get_tree().create_timer(1.0)` will return an object. In particular, `create_timer` returns a `SceneTreeTimer`. And we will be awaiting for this object to emit a signal called `"timeout"`. In fact the `SceneTreeTimer` should emit said signal after one second (the time is specified by the `1.0` argument given to `create_timer`).

---

If you want to look a little deeper into how `yield` works, know that it will schedule the code as a continuation of the signal, and return. So Godot can and will execute other things in the mean time. No thread is blocked. This is similar to C# `await`.

---

Now, in your code:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    yield(get_tree().create_timer(1.0), "timeout")
```

This will do nothing, then await one second, and afterwards do nothing.

And this is unrelated:

```
func timeout():
    print("Working")
```

*I don't think that is how the example in the documentation looks like.*